# Should I use hcidump or btmon for HCI Analysis

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

Should I use `sudo btmon` or `sudo hcidump` to sniff and capture HCI packets for bluetooth debugging?

There is a lot of dated tutorials online. I thought this was a good question to ask and answer for new Linux Bluetooth developers.

Man Page for hcidump https://linux.die.net/man/8/hcidump

Man Page for btmon https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bluez/btmon.1.en.html

Answer (score 1):

hcidump (along with hcitool and other utilities) has been deprecated and is no longer upstreamed. Therefore my recommendation is to use btmon going forward.

More details found below:-

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Troubleshooting
- https://github.com/forksociety/PyBeacon/issues/61